# Missing Rich Text on content WP

Tags: css

This is a question not answered on wordpress.stackoverflow and it won´t be answered cause was placed on hold :(

I have a template made from html to WP, seems to be all was wonking perfectly until I tried to use remarked text with **BOLD** and *Italic text*. all text in post is shown FLAT, only shows pre coded color (theme color font).

```
<div class="property-description">
?php the_content();?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
content {
max-width:1000px;
}
.property-description {
color: #777777;
padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
line-height: 1.4em;

}
```

I have additional lines which no involve the described code, I tried to add a code using `.property-description p{}` to change paragraph but I have same results.
Is there any code to override prior code. The error should be on css on this theme only.

Best Regards!

Comment: Obviously there was a good reason to put the question on hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem that makes that Wordpress doesn't show the formatted text. on the style.css I saw a reset line for most style tags; previously I was used this kind of reset to get a nice responsive site but, today was messy the result to display the rich text content. so I decided to delete some tags from this reset line. 
**the reset lines is this**

`Reset & Basics (Inspired by E. Meyers) 

================================================== */  

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video  

    margin : 0; 

    padding : 0; 

    border : 0; 

    font-size : 100%; 

    font : inherit;  

    vertical-align : baseline;`  

  

  
So I delete the tags  **em, strong, iframe, table**  and others which were breaking the rich text content; Now my site works perfectly.